# Project java with struts and tomcat encoding UTF-8 for POST requests

Tags: tomcat, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to save data in UTF-8, but I'm getting some problems with the encoding :

In my POST request, when I watch it with Firebug I can see the POST request with "Content-Type: text/html".

However, when I watch my action, the HttpServletRequest object has the object connector with the attribute URIEncoding = UTF-8
My jsp page is encoding in UTF-8, (firefox told me and I checked it with notepad++) 
I put -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" in debug configurations/arguments
The tomcat server have URIEncoding = UTF-8 in the file server.xml at the right connector, and in the file web.xml I have the following filter :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

What am I doing wrong, can you help me ?

Comment: I solved it by putting the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my element <html:form>